# Which one is correct - "Good morning both of you" or "Good morning to both of you"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, phrase-usage

I'm quite confused whether good morning everybody, good morning all of you, etc. are correct or good morning to everybody, good morning to all of you, etc. are correct. Please let me know the correct phrase and point out the incorrect ones. If these are correct, what's the difference?
My question is different from the existing question "Good morning, Brian" vs "Good morning to you, Brian".
I want to know which of these are incorrect:
 Good morning everybody! 
 Good morning to everybody! 
 Good morning all of you! 
 Good morning to all of you! 
 Good morning both of you! 
 Good morning to both of you! 
 Good morning, everybody! 
Good morning, both of you!

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but use different mechanisms.

- `Good morning, everybody.` is called [direct address](http://www.softschools.com/examples/grammar/nouns_of_direct_address_examples/59/). N.B. this form requires a comma. Another example: `Lester, please erase the whiteboard.`
- `Good morning to everybody.` makes use of a prepositional phrase to show to whom this is addressed. Another example: `To all a good night.` [Clement Moore]

Answer (score 0):

> "Good morning to everybody."
>
> "Good morning to all of you."

This case is more often used when address people indirectly and formally, such as a meeting or a lecture.  "Good morning to everyone **here today.**" would be something I have heard a professor at a university say when addressing the class.

> "Good morning everybody."
>
> "Good morning all of you."

This is fairly simple, this is used when you want to wish a group of people a good morning.  This is mainly used during conversation between people when both parties are active, however I have heard people say this in the same circumstances as above, as it is still correct, but a bit lazier.